# Stubbed requests with Puffing Billy are also being recorded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm using rspec, capybara and puffing-billy gem for testing the code that works with external services. I want to record some requests and to stub others. The problem is that the requests that is being stubbed is also being recorded by Puffing Billy. Is there a way to configure this gem so that it was not recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look [here](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy) at the section about `Billy.configure`
From your description, it sounds like you should add the requests you do not want recorded to `c.ignore_params`